# Install NZBGet on Raspberry Pi 2 on OSMC

Tags: pi-2

I have recently installed OSMC Alpha 4 on my Raspberry Pi 2. I have ssh'd into it and am wondering how to install NZBGet. The tutorials I have found are for RPi 1 and are a few months old. Is the procedure the same? and where can I install unrar from?

I also would like it to start at boot, is this possible without upstart?

The tutorial is here: http://www.htpcguides.com/install-nzbget-14-raspberry-pi-with-raspbian/

Comment: You should link to the tutorials so someone answering can check the procedure to determine any differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those instructions target the OS, Raspbian, and not any particular pi model.  So if you are using Raspbian, they should be fine.

If you have a screen and keyboard attached, you don't have to do the thing with `screen` when you compile, just leave it running.  That's this part:

```
./configure --with-tlslib=OpenSSL && make && sudo make install && sudo make install-conf
```

Instead, do those one at a time and add `-j4` to the `make`:

```
./configure --with-tlslib=OpenSSL
make -j4
sudo make install
sudo make install-conf
```

The `-j4` may speed things up by exploiting the four cores.  If so, that step should only take 5-10 minutes on the pi 2 instead of 20 -- on the other hand, it may take almost as long if there is not enough stuff to do in parallel.

---

If you are using jessie, the `unrar` version mentioned at the beginning can be gotten [here](http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/non-free/u/unrar-nonfree/unrar-nonfree_5.0.10.orig.tar.gz) (that's a link into [this repo](http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/non-free/u/unrar-nonfree/)).  Download that to the pi and:

```
tar -xzf unrar-nonfree_5.0.10.orig.tar.gz
cd unrar
make -j4
sudo make install
```

You'll probably need `sudo apt-get install build-essential libsigc++-dev` first.

Comment: Thank you for the help. OSMC appears to be based on Debian Jessie. So it's nearly Raspbian. But is it  close enough?

Comment: It looks like OSMC uses Raspbian ("For now, we’re using an ARMv7 kernel with a Raspbian based filesystem"), so it should be fine.  I've added a few paragraphs at the end that should simplify installing the `unrar` version mentioned in the NZBget page.

Comment: Once I try it I will. Busy cleaning the house :-)

Comment: This worked up until I installed "upstart" and did a reboot. It now hangs on reboot at: "Starting avahi nDMS/DSM-SD Daemon: avahi-daemon"

Comment: Well, here is [what Avahi is](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avahi_(software)).  I don't think NZBget would configure anything there.  And I don't think Avahi would make use of `unrar`, so that's not it.  Seems like possibly an unrelated issue.  If you can mount the second partition and find which script in `/etc/init.d` starts avahi (hopefully it is just called that, if not you could `grep -i avahi /etc/init.d/*`), you could temporarily move it (e.g. `avahi` -> `avahi.tmp`) to disable, try booting, and maybe `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`.

Comment: The whole Pi has frozen, I'll have to start from scratch as I cannot mount it on anything else to do as you suggest. It appeared to be an 'upstart' issue?

Comment: Oh whoops, missed that part about you installing upstart -- that's definitely the problem (and what I suggested about `init.d` won't fix it).  I'd avoid that.  Debian is moving from SysV init to systemd (not upstart; in fact jessie, including raspbian jessie, use systemd by default) and Ubuntu is I think going to abandon upstart (for systemd) in the not so distant future.  So pretty much all the major distros will be systemd based; fedora and arch are already.

Comment: How then do I get nzbget to start at boot along with say Sickrage

Comment: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/28199/raspberry-pi-starting-programs-automatically-on-startup

Answer (score 0):

Upstart is not necessary and it is probably easiest to use a crontab which OSMC has disabled by default so you'll have to enable the service first.

There are now easier instructions for the latest NZBGet on the Raspberry Pi and other ARM devices http://www.htpcguides.com/install-latest-nzbget-on-raspberry-pi-2-and-b-raspbian/ which will allow you to autoupdate to new versions in the future without building from source or waiting on a repo.