# Camera not working with script started with .bashrc

Tags: camera, noobs

**Running NOOBS**

**Raspberry pi 3b**

**Standard Camera from Pihut**

So, my grand idea is to have a camera taking still images (raspistill) that I can then stitch together later, to make a short movie seen out through the windscreen of our motorhome.

So I have managed to make a script that works perfect for this, if I run the script after booting and logging in to my PI.

Now, obviously I do not want to login to my pi to start the script every time, I want it to work as I power on my pi.
Here starts my problems. After searching high and low, I have found that the way to do that in NOOBS (at least with still logging in) is to call the script in **.bashrc** - So I did. I can run every script fine, but if I want to use the camera I now get this error.

```
mmal: mmal_vc_component_enable: failed to enable component: ENOSPC
mmal: camera component couldn't be enabled
mmal: main: Failed to create camera component
mmal: Failed to run camera app. Please check for firmware updates
```

And if I try to close the script and restart it (or others with camera code) I keep getting this error until I reboot with out the script being run on boot.

I have spend a lot of time trying to figure out what I do wrong. I have even tried to make a separate script that I run from **.bashrc** that will then sleep 100 seconds (just to be extra **extra** sure) and then opens my camera script, still same problem.

What am I doing wrong? Is it just NOOBS that are unable to do what I ask or am I doing something completely wrong?
My real goal is to have a script start when I power on the Pi, without logging in, that I can start taking pictures with a push of a button.

**Here is the code of the camera script I use:** (yes I am using raspistill instead of timelaps)

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import os
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(24, GPIO.OUT)

x = 0

def runner(x):
        print("***** RUNNER: " + str(x))
        if x < 5:
                StorageLeft = os.popen("df -Ph /dev/sda1 | grep -Po '\d+(?=%)'").read()
                print("Storage left: " + str(100-int(StorageLeft)) + "%")


                for p in range(0,int(StorageLeft)):
                        GPIO.output(24, True)
                        time.sleep(0.5)
                        GPIO.output(24, False)
                        time.sleep(0.5)

        if x > 4:
                t = 0
                while True:
                        print("Picture: " + str(t))
                        os.system("raspistill -w 640 -h 480 -o /media/pi/TEST/" + str(t) + ".jpg")
                        GPIO.output(24, True)
                        t += 1
                        time.sleep(1)
                        input_state = GPIO.input(18)
                        if input_state==False:
                                print("Break")
                                break
                        GPIO.output(24, False)
                        time.sleep(4)
                        StorageLeft = os.popen("df -Ph /dev/sda1 | grep -Po '\d+(?=%)'").read()
                        print("Storage left: " + str(100-int(StorageLeft)) + "%")
                        if 100-int(StorageLeft) < 99:
                                print("***** Card full, script ended")
                                break

while True:
    input_state = GPIO.input(18)
    if input_state==False:
        x += 1
        print(x)
        time.sleep(1)
    else:
        if x > 0:
                runner(x)
                x = 0
```

Comment: What version of OS are you running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that it all worked with using @reboot in **crontab**. Much easier way to get around my problem.

Answer (score 2):

You want to run a script/program at startup without login. This is
usually done with a service and managed by `systemd`. This isn't really a
raspi specific question but here is a very short snipped to give an idea.
Create a new service for `camera.service`:

```
pi ~$ sudo systemctl edit --force --full camera.service
```

Insert this statements with your settings, save them and quit the editor:

```
[Unit]
Description=Camera script

[Service]
ExecStart=/path/to/camera.py
StandardOutput=null

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then enable this service:

```
pi ~$ sudo systemctl enable camera.service
pi ~$ sudo systemctl start camera.service
```

Of course this will not fit your specifc needs. You may need to start other services and start your script before or after them. This can be defined in section `[Unit]`. There are many examples out there on google. Please have a look at them. You may look here for [starting after "network-up"](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/79033/79866).

Comment: Okay, thank you. I will have a look into it tonight .

Answer (score 0):

`.bashrc` is **NOT** intended to run scripts.

It is run each time a shell is started.
`~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells`.

There are may ways of running scripts, but it unclear what you are trying to do. The listing does not look like a `bash` script but looks like `Python`

See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/47537/8697 for an example.

Comment: You are right, it is a .py file, i could just only find the .bash method. But as you say, its mixing the wrong things.