# systemd: hand-made service fails to start on boot

Tags: boot-issues, services, systemd

I created an application that I want to start on boot for the raspberry.

I had already set up a service for wvdial by hand to make it start on boot and it works like a charm so I then started working on this application of mine. It's no fancy stuff, it's a "simple" service with a command to start, I defined the working directory and the user that will run it.

```
[Unit]
Description=Blah Blah

[Service]
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi/appdir
ExecStart=/home/pi/appdir/the-script-to-start.py
Restart=always
RestartSec=60
User=pi
```

When booting, it's not started (systemd says it's **inactive (dead)**). No output about it on journalctl. If I then try starting by hand with systemctl, it works.

What am I missing?

**PS1**

Ok.... I think python (or the basic set up to get it working) is not to blame. I switched to configuring a very simple bash script that just prints a line and nothing else... so it goes out with exit code 0.

After rebooting:

```
● my-service.service - some Service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/my-service.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

When I run it manually:

```
● my-service.service - some Service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/my-service.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) since Wed 2018-04-11 16:00:55 UTC; 2s ago
  Process: 744 ExecStart=/home/pi/blahblah/prueba.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 744 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

Is there something I can do in systemd configuration so that I can see more debugging information about how it's working on boot?

**PS2**

After modifying LogLevel to debug and reboot, I can see that for wvdial, we have this info from journalctl about 22 seconds into boot process (for starters, there's more stuff ):

```
Apr 11 16:53:06 raspberrypi systemd[1]: wvdial.service: Trying to enqueue job wvdial.service/start/replace
Apr 11 16:53:06 raspberrypi systemd[1]: wvdial.service: Installed new job wvdial.service/start as 182
Apr 11 16:53:06 raspberrypi systemd[1]: wvdial.service: Enqueued job wvdial.service/start as 182
Apr 11 16:53:06 raspberrypi systemd[1]: wvdial.service: Passing 0 fds to service
Apr 11 16:53:06 raspberrypi systemd[1]: wvdial.service: About to execute: /usr/bin/wvdial
Apr 11 16:53:06 raspberrypi systemd[1]: wvdial.service: Forked /usr/bin/wvdial as 498
Apr 11 16:53:06 raspberrypi systemd[1]: wvdial.service: Changed dead -> running
Apr 11 16:53:06 raspberrypi systemd[1]: wvdial.service: Job wvdial.service/start finished, result=done
Apr 11 16:53:06 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started wvdial service.
Apr 11 16:53:06 raspberrypi systemd[498]: wvdial.service: Executing: /usr/bin/wvdial
```

But no word about my service.

Comment: It doesn't meet your needs exactly but maybe you can find some hints at [Running a script after an internet connection is established](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/79033/79866).

Comment: Please check the FAQ *[Why do things behave differently under systemd?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/339645/20239). Also, is your service trying to do something graphical, like launch a desktop app?

Comment: @MarkStosberg Will take a look. And no, it's a pure shell based application that uses a GPS device attached to the raspberry.

Comment: when I ask systemctl to list units (--all), I can see wvdial, but I can't see anything about the other service. Grrrrrrr

Answer (score 2):

[Unit]
After=?

[Install] 
WantedBy=?

Or //
does the script have the python shebang? is it +x? 
if both are set and still not working try to add the /usr/bin/python infront to the ExecStart 
// 
But i think its After=/Before= // WantedBy=

```
[Unit]
Description=Scanner Script Service
After=server.service multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/opt/files/
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /opt/files/scanner.py
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

(working, server.service is a selfmade too)

Comment: Script does have shebang. It's also set with +x. Let me try adding the python binary to the call to see if that solves it.

Comment: Ok.... I think python (or the basic set up to get it working) is not to blame. I switched to configuring a very simple bash script that just prints a line and nothing else... so it goes out with exit code 0. If I run it manually.... I'll add a comment.... I know that formatting does't work here

Answer (score 2):

Seems this is already solved, but wanted to add an alternative solution for starting a Python program (or any program for that matter) at boot time:

open `crontab` as follows:

> crontab -e

the crontab will be opened in your chosen editor (default is nano)

Add a line to the end of your crontab file that looks like this:

> @reboot   /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/any-program.py > /home/pi/cronjoblog 2>&1

Your program named `any-program.py` will execute during the boot sequence, and any issues will be recorded in the file `cronjoblog`

Comment: Didn't know about this possibility. Nice touch! It's still more flexible with systemd because it's possible to stop/start at will but still nice to know.

Answer (score -1):

Seems like adding the section [Install] and enabling the service, it starts working (I didn't have to do it with wvdial but....).

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: No need to add this as new answer, this is what @ghost advised. Adding the [Install] section and running 'enable' is what sets the service to be started at boot time.