# How to run python script on raspberry boot up?

Tags: camera

I am making a project which contains face and object recognition. I activated functions with push button. My question is how can i run automatically my GPIO script when reboot raspberry.

I've tried write in .bashrc file. But it causes error(i guess
 its about camera) that;

mmal: mmal_vc_component_enable: failed to enable component: ENOSPC
mmal: camera component couldn't be enabled.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Make a service to start with `systemd`.

Comment: Can you explain more specific ?

Comment: Try to make a service with `systemd`. I don't make it for you. Look at the internet. There are many examples. You can also look at `man  systemd.unit`. If you get stuck with a specific problem on this I can help you. To give you an idea you can look at this [example for a systemd service](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/79033/79866). And please take the [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute script on start-up](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8734/execute-script-on-start-up)

Comment: Please be more specific about your problem, i.e. you give us an error message but not the script itself you try to run. That way possible answers are just guesswork. Provide all relevant input and make sure to outline how your issue is not covered by the more generic example given in the Q&A linked by Aurora. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this quite easily by adding a line to your `crontab` file. Do this:

From your $ shell prompt, enter `man crontab`. Read what it says. When you finish, dismiss the man page be entering `q`, and then enter `crontab -e` on the command line.

The `nano` editor will start, and show you a "default" crontab in which each line is commented - it begins with "#". Using `nano`, move the insertion point to the first new line at the end of the file. Enter this:

`@reboot /usr/bin/python3 ~/somefolder/somefile.py &`

Where ~/ is your home directory (probably /home/pi), "somefolder" is a folder in your home directory containing the Python script you want to run, and "somefile.py" is your Python script. The `&` lets your Python script run "in the background", and doesn't hold things up.

After you've added this line, use `nano`'s `Write` (`^O`) to save the file, and accept whatever filename it suggests. Then exit `nano` using `^X`. You'll get a confirmation message that your crontab file has been updated.

Reboot your pi, and your Python script will execute; and it will execute each time your pi reboots.