# .bashrc is executed once on boot and another time when terminal autostart via @lxterminal [repost with correct account]

Tags: boot, bash

I am using .bashrc to execute a python script on system boot:

```
sudo -u pi python3 /path/to/script.py
```

and then I add @lxterminal to file /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart to make sure a terminal window is opened on launch.

however, when I use ps aux to check all progresses, I found that there's two script.py processes running in the system, even though I call execute the script only once in .bashrc. Having two of the same script running at the same time is causing me troubles. Any help is appreciated.

yes ive tried with the other methods but couldn't get them to work. THe curious thing is that i have 5 pis all configured the same way, but one of them only executes the script once. Apparently it is only executing the script when the terminal is opened and not when the system boots. any ideas here? rc.local method never worked for me as nothing happened on startup

Comment: Please delete your [question with the wrong account](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/117039/79866).

Comment: "*ive tried with the other methods but couldn't get them to work*" - Please explain what problems did you have using a systemd service. Can you post the Unit file you used?

Comment: Hi Ingo, I appreciate everything you putting your time and effort into helping me. But i just really need to stick to bashrc because of time constraints. I just want to know why on one of my pis bashrc does not seem to execute until @lxterminal brings up a terminal, while in the other 4 pis, bashrc executes before this at boot

Comment: This question is [cross-posted to at least one other SE site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/610333/command-in-bashrc-is-being-executed-twice). Cross-posting is frowned upon - [please read this explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Answer (score 3):

There are different methods to start a script on bootup. Using `~/.bashrc` is definitely a wrong method. It is only made to configure the bash shell when it is launched. So every time the bash shell is executed your python script will also start. Your script is started with `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart` and it is also started with the bash shell. So you have it running two times. It may be running some more times, depending on how often bash is started.

You can use a cron job or create a systemd service. Please search for [start python script on boot](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/search?q=start+python+script+on+boot).

Comment: yes ive tried with the other methods but couldn't get them to work. THe curious thing is that i have 5 pis all configured the same way, but one of them only executes the script once. Apparently it is only executing the script when the terminal is opened and not when the system boots. any ideas here? rc.local method never worked for me as nothing happened on startup

Comment: Please [edit](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/117043/edit) your question and add the additional information to it. Don't use comments for it. As soon as you have deleted your dupplicate question, I will continue answering.

Comment: sorry i used an guest account to post that question and have no idea how to log back into that guest account to delete the question

Answer (score 0):

`.bashrc` is **NOT** intended to run scripts.

It is run each time a non-login interactive shell is started and is used to configure the shell.
`~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells`.

There are may ways of running scripts, depending on what you are trying to do.
See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/47537/8697 for an example.

Comment: i have to use .bashrc. if you check my addition in the post, one of my 5 pis works fine, when it starts up, .bashrc contents are only executed once.

Comment: You **DO NOT** "have to use .bashrc". No matter what you may have done it will cause problems. It **DOES NOT** run on boot.

Comment: does it help to know that when i do ps aux, i see the scripts are executed once as pi and once as root?

Comment: does it help to know that when i do ps aux, i see the scripts are executed once as pi and once as root?

Comment: @MichaelChang It doesn't help anything if you use .bashrc.

Comment: my python script is a continuous client that sends information to a server, the current bashrc + lxterminal combination allows to see the output of the program in realtime quite nicely. I just tried systemd, it did not work as well, thus i would like to stick to the bashrc method. also I can guarantee that only one terminal will be opened on the pis. thus bashrc's weaknesses really do not apply here i think.

Comment: @MichaelChang Again - please don't use comments for additional information, add it to the question.