# Detect keystrokes for a program at boot

Tags: raspbian, python, boot, keyboard

I would like to create a python program to detect when a certain key (W,A,S,D) is pressed so for example, while the *w* key is pressed, the def forward() is activated and when it is let go, it stops the motor. How would I do this so that as soon as the pi boots up, my keystrokes are detected and the program responds accordingly?

**Example program**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import explorerhat
import sys, tty, termios, time

def left():
    explorerhat.motor.one.forward(75)
def right():
    explorerhat.motor.one.backward(75)


while True:
    char = input()

    if(char=="a"):
            left()

    if(char=="d"):
            right()

    if(char=="x"):
            break

    char = ""

explorerhat.motor.one.stop()
```

Thanks! This is to control a little robot I'm building.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `input()`, you will need to press `Enter` after every keystroke.  Instead, you might want to use a function that accepts keypresses, rather than lines of input.  A starting point is in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12175964/python-method-for-reading-keypress).

There are various ways to get your programme to start when the RPi boots up. Some of them are [listed here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/28199/raspberry-pi-starting-programs-automatically-on-startup).

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import explorerhat
import sys, tty, termios, time

def left():
    explorerhat.motor.one.forward(75)
def right():
    explorerhat.motor.one.backwatd(75)


while True:
    char = input()

    if(char=="a"):
        left()
    else:
        if(char != "a")
             explorerhat.motor.one.stop()

    if(char=="d"):
        right()
    else:
        if(char != "d")
           explorerhat.motor.one.stop()

    if(char=="x"):
        break

    char = ""

explorerhat.motor.one.stop()
```