# How to start a python3 script on startup without login? (stretch image)

Tags: boot, script, python-3, raspbian-stretch

I am trying to start a python script called "irremote.py" on startup (currently in my home directory).

I am running raspbian-stretch on a Pi Zero W, and I would like the script to start without a login or other user input.  I will not be using this Pi Zero for anything else.

I've done some research into the topic and found a variety of different methods, some which appear to be outdated.

What is the best way I can start my python 3 script?

Comment: Choose the best for you.  If it doesn't work please show what you have done and we may be able to help.

Comment: It looks a bit like a déjà vu: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/28199/13700

Answer (score 1):

On a system without a *systemd daemon* running you can put a startup script calling your python program in **/etc/init.d** - e.g. /etc/init.d/go-go-go and then soft-link to it from inside the desired runlevel - check what runlevel your machine is in after booting by issueing the command

```
runlevel
```

You'll get an answer like

```
N 3
```

or

```
N 5
```

Whatever - say it's 2 - then you'd go to /etc/rc2.d and softlink like so:

```
ln -s /etc/init.d/go-go-go S99go-irremote
```

For the systemd approach you need to create a **service** file in **/etc/systend/system** - e.g. **irremote.service**:

```
[Unit]
Description=do the IR remote stuff I like

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/pi/irremote.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

In any case I suggest reading

```
man runlevel
```

Comment: I tried using the systemd approach, and it won't start the script until I login

Comment: Okay it's not the service that's starting the program on login, it's something else I setup earlier.  When I check the status of my service, it says it failed with result 'exit-code' and has a status=203/EXEC.  Is there a way to see the output of my program.  Also, do I need to add something like "#!" at the start of my irremote.py file?

Comment: Of course you need the shebang - "#!/usr/bin/python" - and be sure to make it executable. Regarding output I would suggest logging to a file from inside the script.

Answer (score 0):

Look for `@reboot` in `man 5 crontab`.

Using `@reboot` in the user's `crontab` (see `man 1 crontab`, especially `crontab -e`) you can wire a script to be run after reboot without needing superuser privileges to define or run this.

I'm using this way to start `screen` after reboot:

```
@reboot screen -c ~/.screenrc.cron-autostart -dmS `hostname`
```

I see no reason why `python3` should misbehave when started with a script this way:

```
@reboot python3 path/to/script.py script arguments
```

If your program needs to be nannied from time to time or if you want to see its output, starting it in `screen` or just redirecting its output to somewhere or logging may be needed.